# Lambda expression filtering included related data with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, filtering

I need to filter only the visibles products from a category, but it's not working.

```
Category category = db.Categories
            .Include(c => c.Products.Where(p => p.IsVisible))
            .First(c => c.CategoryID == id);
```

Error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

UPDATE

```
 var result = (from c in db.Categories
                             where c.CategoryID == id
                             select new
                             {
                                 CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                                 Description = c.Description,
                                 Products = (from p in db.Products
                                             where p.IsVisible
                                             && p.CategoryID == c.CategoryID
                                             orderby p.DateSent descending
                                             select p)
                             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

but now i need to cast the anonymousType to Category

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035261/include-using-lambda-expression

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't make sense if you want:

> the visibles products from a category

If you genuinely want the visible products, try this:

```
var visibleProducts = db.Categories
                        .Where(c => c.CategoryID == id)
                        .Select(c => c.Products.Where(p => p.IsVisible));
```

Note: untested

Comment: i'll test, but i need the category data plus a list of visible products

Comment: You already have the id of the category, you could just make it 2 queries. First query gets the category, second query gets the visible products from the category. That way you have both.

Comment: i know that i can use 2 queries, but due performece it would be nice to make it using only 1.

Comment: There won't be a performance issue, it already has to do those 2 queries anyway. Might as well just store the results from both separately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
var category = db.Products.Where(p=>p.IsVisible && p.CategoryID == id).Include("Category").ToList().Select( p=> p.Category).Distinct();
```

It may not be ideal because of the ToList... but I can see no other way right now.

Maybe you could change the Distinct into a FirstOrDefault()...

```
var category = db.Products.Where(p=>p.IsVisible && p.CategoryID == id).Include("Category").ToList().FirstOrDefault().Category;
```

Not tested either...